# Django Apps aren't loaded yet error

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm still new to Django, but when I run python manage.py runserver, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10363f2a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/ashih/Desktop/ProjectX/website/mysite/toa/models.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Absolutedollarvalue(models.Model):
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/ashih/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Does this mean that the problem is with INSTALLED_APPS? toa is the name of the app, and toa.models.absolutedollarvalue is the name of one of the tables in models.py.

Can anyone tell me what my issue is? This is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5@cpwno*vprze+^yy*v*7cucs!ein)(3_i6s+ut7&r28)520!-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'toa',
    'toa.models.Absolutedollarvalue'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'px1',
        'USER': 'ashih',
        'PASSWORD': ' ',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I'm trying to query the database in my views.py and then pass it to a template to display using highcharts.js. However, the server won't run right now, so I can't figure out if my queries are working or if they're even displaying properly.

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to leave `toa.models.Absolutedollarvalue` out of your `INSTALLED_APPS`, it is loaded during the load of your `toa` app (the line above it) You do not have to load your files within your app individually. You are now trying to load your model as an individual app.

If toa is a python/django lib you haven't written, then it might be caused due to a version incompatibility issue